# Unable to process expanded row data in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, expansion

This is my xhtml code containing a datatable using row expansion. Using primefaces 4.0, jsf mozarra 2.2.4

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{myBean.lazyModel}" var="dd"
    rowKey="#{dd.hashCode()}" paginator="true"
    selection="#{myBean.myModel.selectedRecords}" rows="#{myBean.pageSize}"
    paginatorPosition="top"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}   
                       {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}             {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20,50,100" widgetVar="dataTable"
    currentPageReportTemplate="(Number of Records: {totalRecords})"
    lazy="true">  
     <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{myBean.onRowToggle}" process="@this"/>
<p:column>
    <p:rowToggler />
</p:column>

<p:column selectionMode="multiple" id="select" />

<p:column id="cpn" headerText="#{messages['cpn']}"
    filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{dd.cpn}" filterBy="#{dd.cpn}">
    <p:inputText id="cpnid" value="#{dd.cpn}" />
</p:column>
<p:column id="user" headerText="#{messages['user']}"
    filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{dd.number}"
    filterBy="#{dd.number}">
    <p:inputText id="addid" value="#{dd.number}" />
</p:column>
   :
   :    
<p:rowExpansion id="rowExpansion">
    <p:panelGrid>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{messages['name']}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="name" name="txtBox" value="#{dd.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{messages['ageGroup']}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="agecol">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="agegrp" value="#{dd.agegrp}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="21-25" itemValue="21-25" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="26-30" itemValue="26-30" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
    </p:rowExpansion>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Now I expanded a row and entered name and selected age group and collapsed the row. If I reexpand the same row I couldn't see the values I have entered. When I debugged on collapsing the row The name field and age grp fields setters are called with null parameters.

If I remove the ajax rowToggle event then there is no request is sent to the server on row collapse.

All the examples I found are showing only static data on row expansion.

Is there any way to process data user entered on row collapse?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Do you use this datatable in a dialog?

Try set `dynamic=false` in parent dialog. 
Dynamic dialog may override your ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<p:ajax partialSubmit="true" />` inside each input forms

Comment: partialSubmit is to restrict the post data to only components mentioned in process attribute. How does it help in mycase?

Comment: "When partialSubmit is enabled, only data of components that will be partially processed on the
server side are serialized." Your current Object will be update and normally when you reexpand the row you will see the values you have entered, that's what you want ?

Comment: H I am aware of it and tried that also but no use. If they add ajax request on row collapse also to the component it would of so much help.But i think they are interested in that way. see here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9161&sid=bb9d1daed1415d214b1971626e23f0b9#p75573

Answer (score 0):

Just remove sortBy from child table.
It's works to me.

Or,
In xhtml file (MasterDataTable):

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{superView.ontoggle()}" />
```

On View file:

```
public void ontoggle() {
    UIComponent table = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:MasterDataTable:ChildDataTable");
    if (table != null) {
        table.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
    }
}
```